# EJB's and JPA: Update on database will not show on page until server is restarted

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I have built an application with EJB's and JPA2.  If I have my page running and I change something in the database it will not show on the page.  I've tried different browsers, non caching sessions of the browsers, etc.  The only way I can see the new data is if I restart glassfish 3.1.  I have gone through debugging and it's obviously building a new list every time but the data it's getting is old.

Here is my findAll method.

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

Is there a setting on glassfish/ejb that tells it not to cache the database?  Or something similar to this.

Just want to reiterate that restarting Glassfish fixes the problem.  Until the next change of course.

Comment: have you tried explicitly flushing the persistence context when you do your update?  Can we see the update code?

Comment: I'm actually just doing any update manually through a mysql query.

Comment: Thanks man.  I was able to change the cache mode and that fixed the problem.

I added this to the persistence.xml
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>

If you add an answer I will give you some rep.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also provide [refresh hint for EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Query_Hints#Refresh) for your query. It should help and is more fine grained than completely turning off cache.